# AsyncTask, LinearLayout Android Update visibility

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-linearlayout

I am trying to change visibility of a Linear Layout through findViewById() and then SetVisiblity(). But When I debug, I am seeing null values only.

Please find the snippet in the BackgroundMainActivity.java below in the onPostExecute() method.

I commented it. Please help.

MainActivity.java

```
button_getUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BackgroundMainActivity backgroundMainActivity = new BackgroundMainActivity(MainActivity.this, v);
            backgroundMainActivity.execute("random", editText_username.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

BackgroundMainActivity.java

```
public class BackgroundMainActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {


    public BackgroundMainActivity(Context ct, View view) {
        context = ct;
        rootView = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String login_URL = "some url";
        try {
            String username = params[1];

            URL url = new URL(login_URL);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));

            result = bufferedReader.readLine();

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String result){
        if(result.equals("success")){

//need to make this change
//LinearLayout someLayout = (LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.layout_content);
//someLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(result)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",null)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

activity_main.xml

ss_layout_questions is gone by default. I want to make it visible once "result.equals( "success") " in BackgroundMainActivity.java.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.xtremustechnologies.chotu.useractivity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/lightGreen"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textviewr2"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="CHOTU"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="40dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:text="Your Personal Assistant"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ss_textview_questions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:text="Security Questions "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ss_et_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Username" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ss_button_getusername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ss_et_username"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:onClick="clickGetUsername"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Submit" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ss_layout_questions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textviewr3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ss_button_dob"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:text="Date of Birth" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ss_textView_dob"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ss_textView_question1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ss_textView_ans1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Enter your answer here" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ss_textView_question2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ss_textView_ans2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Enter your answer here" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ss_textView_question3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ss_textView_ans3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Enter your answer here" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ss_button_submit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean "null values only."? is that NullPointerException ? can you post some log please

Comment: BackgroundMainActivity backgroundMainActivity = new BackgroundMainActivity(MainActivity.this, v); don't pass v directly. Take View Object from layout file.

Comment: viewroot comes from the v parameter of onClick() which seems to be set on a button right? That would imply that viewroot is the button that was clicked and you are calling findViewById on a button. Is this what you intend to do?

Comment: @L.Swifter in debug, I see "someLayout = null", but when I try to do a similar assignment in MainActivity.java, I am seeing a value getting assigned. This error is only with BackgroundMainActivity.java.

Comment: @Abhishek could you show a small snippet. I'm not sure what you meant by get the View Object but not v.

Comment: @Juan no. My intention was to findViewById of a LinearLayout which is in the context of the MainActivity.

Comment: @SeshagiriRaoKornepati put your XML file. I will try to elaborate.

Comment: @Abhishek I added. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Its working finally. Here is what I did

I added a new class inside BackgroundMainActivity.java and then called it in the onPostExecute() method.

```
class a{

public Button button_reset, button_dob;
public LinearLayout layout_questions;
public TextView textView_title;
public EditText editText_username;

public void makeVisible(ForgotPasswordActivity context){

    LinearLayout layout_questions = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.ss_layout_questions);
    layout_questions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

onPostExecute() in BackgroundMainActivity.java

```
a obj = new a();
        obj.makeVisible((ForgotPasswordActivity) context);
```

Comment: One more thing to consider. As you are passing a reference to the Activity to the AsyncTask, you should store the activity (context) in a WeakReference because it could happen that when the AsyncTask finishis, the context could be null. And keeping a reference will introduce a memory leak into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should get `NPE` error. Why? Because look at this code:

```
button_getUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BackgroundMainActivity backgroundMainActivity = new BackgroundMainActivity(MainActivity.this, v);
        backgroundMainActivity.execute("random", editText_username.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Here, you are trying to pass a `Button` (your `button_getUserName`) to your `AsyncTask`. Then when you find the view, of course, there's no layout in your button.

How to resolve it? Actually, it's very easy, just pass your layout in the constructor of the `AsyncTask` as:

```
BackgroundMainActivity backgroundMainActivity = new BackgroundMainActivity(MainActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.layout_content));
// do on onPost:v.setVisibility...
```